# in file explorer only explore upto data/data/

Tags: android

I wrote the following statement:

```
db.getPath();
```

and it returns the following value:

```
data/data/mypackagename/databasename/tablename
```

But in the file explorer I only get upto `path data/data/`. Everything from there onward is blank. My package is not listed. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access on production hardware to examine those directories using DDMS' File Explorer or any other tool. Your code will be able to access `getPath()` just fine, though.